# ASP.NET Core policy-based authentication not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, authorization

I have to manage our user's roles in our local database, not in Azure AD. But, I also need policy-based authorization for controllers because we have both admin and customer areas.

To handle this, I added an authorization filter that loads the user's role from either `Session` or the database, adds an `Identity` to the `Principal`, and then moves along. This `Identity` adds an appropriate `Role` `Claim`.

Before leaving the authorization filter, the `IsInRole` returns `true` as expected, and there are two `Identities`.

My authorization filter looks like this:

```
public class MyAuthFilter : IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly IUserService userService;

    public MyAuthFilter(IUserService userService)
    {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var user = context.HttpContext.User;

        if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            AuthUserViewModel authUserViewModel;

            var sessionViewModelJson = context.HttpContext.Session.GetString(user.AzureObjectId());
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sessionViewModelJson))
            {
                authUserViewModel = await ConstructSessionViewModel(context);
            }
            else
            {
                authUserViewModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AuthUserViewModel>(sessionViewModelJson);
            }

            user.AddIdentity(authUserViewModel?.Role);
        }
    }

    private async Task<AuthUserViewModel> ConstructSessionViewModel(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var user = context.HttpContext.User;
        var parsedObjectId = Guid.Parse(user.AzureObjectId());

        var findUserResult = await userService.FindByAzureObjectId(new FindByAzureObjectIdRequest
        {
            AzureObjectId = parsedObjectId
        });

        if (findUserResult.Success)
        {
            var userModel = findUserResult.User;

            var viewModel = new AuthUserViewModel
            {
                AzureObjectId = parsedObjectId,
                UserId = userModel.Id,
                SchoolId = userModel.SchoolId.GetValueOrDefault(),
                Name = userModel.Name,
                Email = userModel.Email,
                PhoneNumber = userModel.PhoneNumber,
                Role = userModel.Role
            };

            context.HttpContext.Session.SetString(user.AzureObjectId(), JsonConvert.SerializeObject(viewModel));

            return viewModel;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

That `AddIdentity` extension method looks like this:

```
public static void AddIdentity(this ClaimsPrincipal principal, string role)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(role) || principal.IsInRole(role))
    {
        return;
    }

    switch (role)
    {
        case Roles.School:
            principal.AddIdentity(new SchoolIdentity());
            break;
        case Roles.Admin:
            principal.AddIdentity(new AdminIdentity());
            break;
    }
}
```

and in this case, the `SchoolIdentity` is what gets added, and it looks like this:

```
public class SchoolIdentity : ClaimsIdentity
{
    public SchoolIdentity()
    {
        AddClaim(new SchoolPortalClaim());
    }
}
```

and finally, the `SchoolPortalClaim` looks like this:

```
public class SchoolPortalClaim : Claim
{
    public SchoolPortalClaim() : base(ClaimTypes.Role, "School")
    {
    }

    public SchoolPortalClaim(BinaryReader reader) : base(reader)
    {
    }

    public SchoolPortalClaim(BinaryReader reader, ClaimsIdentity subject) : base(reader, subject)
    {
    }

    protected SchoolPortalClaim(Claim other) : base(other)
    {
    }

    protected SchoolPortalClaim(Claim other, ClaimsIdentity subject) : base(other, subject)
    {
    }

    public SchoolPortalClaim(string type, string value) : base(type, value)
    {
    }

    public SchoolPortalClaim(string type, string value, string valueType) : base(type, value, valueType)
    {
    }

    public SchoolPortalClaim(string type, string value, string valueType, string issuer) : base(type, value, valueType, issuer)
    {
    }

    public SchoolPortalClaim(string type, string value, string valueType, string issuer, string originalIssuer) : base(type, value, valueType, issuer, originalIssuer)
    {
    }

    public SchoolPortalClaim(string type, string value, string valueType, string issuer, string originalIssuer, ClaimsIdentity subject) : base(type, value, valueType, issuer, originalIssuer, subject)
    {
    }
}
```

The issue comes when the policy executes:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(Policies.School,
        policy => policy.RequireAssertion(
            context => context.User.IsInRole(Roles.School)));
});
```

The `context.User` does not have the `Identity` that was added by the authorization filter.

How do I get this to move downstream?

The `Controller` in question looks like this:

```
[Area(Areas.School)]
[Authorize(Policy = Policies.School)]
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    public HomeController(IUserService userService) :
        base(userService)
    {
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Presentation", new {Area = "School"});
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you registered app.UseAuthentication(), could you please show startup.cs to us?

Comment: @Tisa, yes that is included currently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fundamental issue here is that the `RequireAssertion` callback gets invoked before `IAsyncAuthorizationFilter.OnAuthorizationAsync`, which means the `ClaimsIdentity` you add in `OnAuthorizationAsync` has not been added at the time you need it.

Instead of using a custom authz filter, you can turn to a custom implementation of [`IClaimsTransformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.iclaimstransformation), which declares a [`TransformAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.iclaimstransformation.transformasync#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authentication_IClaimsTransformation_TransformAsync_System_Security_Claims_ClaimsPrincipal_) method. This method takes the current `ClaimsPrincipal` and allows you to return either the same `ClaimsPrincipal` or a new one, according to your needs.

Here's a skeleton example:

```
public class MyClaimsTransformation : IClaimsTransformation
{
    public async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        // Your existing logic to add the relevant ClaimsIdentity.
        // You might want to check if the ClaimsPrincipal already contains either
        // SchoolIdentity or AdminIdentity here, as this operation may run
        // more than once.
        // ...
    }
}
```

To register this implementation, use something like this, in `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddSingleton<IClaimsTransformation, MyClaimsTransformation>();
```